# will there be pairwise disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

1. $S$ can not be finite
2. S can not be countably infinite.
3. S can not be uncountably infinite
4. S is empty.

1 is wrong I can take any finite no of disjoint open sets by housdorff property I can find right?

2 is also wrong I can take points from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and seperate them by those pairwise disjoint open sets so here S is countably infinite,

3 is also wrong I will do the same thing by putting $\mathbb{Q}^c\times \mathbb{Q}^c$

so 4 is right. Is my arguments are ok?

Comment: $4$ can not be right. Consider  $S$ consisting of two disjoint balls.

Comment: No, $\mathbb{Q}^c \times \mathbb{Q}^c$ is dense. In fact, since 4 is wrong, I think the answer is 3.

Comment: ah!! right thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any disjoint collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable.  You argue as follows.  Let $\mathcal{K}$ be such a collection. For each $k\in K$, choose an element of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ lying in $k$.  This is a 1-1 mapping from the elements of $K$ into a subset of the countable set $\mathbb{Q}^n$.  Therefore $K$ is countable.

In your notation, $S$ can be countable or empty.  It cannot be uncountable.